# For fine particles to get dispersed throughout the globe via atmospheric circulation, in what level of the atmosphere would they have to travel?

Tags: atmospheric-circulation

For molecular-sized particles to disperse around the entire planet, would they have to reach the stratosphere, or could air currents in the troposphere distribute them? Are particles dispersed somewhat equally or are they laid down according to what air current they are swept into?

Comment: jet stream could transport them as well. Depends on the season and depends on the location

Comment: https://blog.breezometer.com/how-air-pollution-moves-between-countries

Comment: Thank you for your help, gansub, especially the link. Do you know of any experiments made to test dispersion of particles via jet streams or other air currents?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lScO-zhMB2o - would this help ? and check the references in this question -https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6608/what-meteorological-factors-contribute-to-springtime-trans-pacific-air-pollution

Comment: you need to give the particle size and the point of release or this will not be possible to answer.

Comment: Molecular-sized. I purposely chose no specific point of release, but for example's sake, how about several points of release: in Belize, in Kenya, in Estonia, in Papua New Guinea (chosen at random by looking at a Mercator map!) I'm curious to know if molecules travel around the entire globe via atmospheric circulation...